turf.area how come the second set of coordinates area is almost 4x as big when its got less coordinates?
Im really confused why the area of the second set of coordinates is almost 4x as large.
square metres of coordinates  = 1,327,834 m2
square metres of coordinates2 = 4,142,357 m2
If you paste the below code in this playground you can visualise the different set of coordinates better
https://turf-sandbox.netlify.app/


const coordinates = [
     [[4.30142,52.12566],[4.29969,52.1264],[4.29793,52.12572],[4.28843,52.11971],[4.28824,52.11866],[4.28669,52.11811],[4.28823,52.11649],[4.28807,52.11575],[4.28815,52.11442],[4.28927,52.11405],[4.29332,52.11328],[4.29582,52.11252],[4.29912,52.11202],[4.3029,52.11097],[4.30547,52.10965],[4.30922,52.10838],[4.31406,52.10647],[4.31912,52.10243],[4.32015,52.10132],[4.32274,52.09919],[4.32312,52.09868],[4.32518,52.09704],[4.32636,52.0965],[4.32902,52.09387],[4.32986,52.09253],[4.3297,52.09227],[4.32979,52.09168],[4.32944,52.0909],[4.32934,52.09018],[4.32836,52.08839],[4.32852,52.08784],[4.32886,52.08748],[4.32833,52.0867],[4.32695,52.08594],[4.32647,52.08534],[4.32569,52.08478],[4.32534,52.08463],[4.32508,52.08473],[4.3239,52.08549],[4.32273,52.08555],[4.32111,52.08703],[4.3166,52.08562],[4.31629,52.08577],[4.31389,52.08836],[4.31304,52.08962],[4.31081,52.09208],[4.30988,52.09341],[4.3083,52.09504],[4.30705,52.09679],[4.30132,52.09945],[4.30073,52.09927],[4.30014,52.09821],[4.30021,52.09721],[4.30001,52.09702],[4.30044,52.09559],[4.3014,52.09454],[4.3023,52.09398],[4.30268,52.0934],[4.30427,52.09183],[4.30468,52.09094],[4.30519,52.0905],[4.30588,52.08947],[4.30601,52.08905],[4.30588,52.08885],[4.3061,52.08847],[4.30884,52.08577],[4.30633,52.08457],[4.3077,52.08356],[4.30922,52.08209],[4.30913,52.08163],[4.30881,52.08128],[4.31024,52.07997],[4.3104,52.07959],[4.3103,52.07888],[4.30985,52.07858],[4.30884,52.07841],[4.30819,52.07789],[4.30912,52.07672],[4.3101,52.0759],[4.30846,52.07541],[4.30142,52.12566]]
];

const coordinates2 = [
   [[4.28669,52.11811],[4.28823,52.11649],[4.28807,52.11575],[4.28815,52.11442],[4.28927,52.11405],[4.29332,52.11328],[4.29582,52.11252],[4.29912,52.11202],[4.3029,52.11097],[4.303522882927534,52.11065007569481],[4.30142,52.12566],[4.29969,52.1264],[4.29793,52.12572],[4.28843,52.11971],[4.28824,52.11866],[4.28669,52.11811]],[[4.30001,52.09702],[4.30044,52.09559],[4.3014,52.09454],[4.3023,52.09398],[4.30268,52.0934],[4.30427,52.09183],[4.30468,52.09094],[4.30519,52.0905],[4.30588,52.08947],[4.30601,52.08905],[4.30588,52.08885],[4.3061,52.08847],[4.306203064337689,52.08836844025118],[4.30623,52.08837],[4.3063822292091825,52.08819189092526],[4.306715236515922,52.08786374503906],[4.305354394770402,52.097577139600475],[4.30132,52.09945],[4.30073,52.09927],[4.30014,52.09821],[4.30021,52.09721],[4.30001,52.09702]],[[4.303522882927534,52.11065007569481],[4.305354394770402,52.097577139600475],[4.30705,52.09679],[4.3083,52.09504],[4.30988,52.09341],[4.31081,52.09208],[4.31304,52.08962],[4.31389,52.08836],[4.31629,52.08577],[4.3166,52.08562],[4.32111,52.08703],[4.32273,52.08555],[4.3239,52.08549],[4.32508,52.08473],[4.32534,52.08463],[4.32569,52.08478],[4.32647,52.08534],[4.32695,52.08594],[4.32833,52.0867],[4.32886,52.08748],[4.32852,52.08784],[4.32836,52.08839],[4.32934,52.09018],[4.32944,52.0909],[4.32979,52.09168],[4.3297,52.09227],[4.32986,52.09253],[4.32902,52.09387],[4.32636,52.0965],[4.32518,52.09704],[4.32312,52.09868],[4.32274,52.09919],[4.32015,52.10132],[4.31912,52.10243],[4.31406,52.10647],[4.30922,52.10838],[4.30547,52.10965],[4.303522882927534,52.11065007569481]],[[4.30633,52.08457],[4.307274211471829,52.08387390249157],[4.307152468258833,52.08474287926047],[4.30651,52.08447],[4.30657587,52.08438874],[4.30633,52.08457]],[[4.306715236515922,52.08786374503906],[4.307123537538409,52.08494938049645],[4.307123539780287,52.08494938156826],[4.30672554,52.08779022],[4.30723,52.0872],[4.308317240364933,52.08628512810755],[4.306715236515922,52.08786374503906]],[[4.307274211471829,52.08387390249157],[4.308041172033484,52.07839950359623],[4.30733293,52.0834548],[4.30758,52.08315],[4.3082,52.0829],[4.30837,52.08257],[4.30917964,52.08188373],[4.30913,52.08163],[4.30922,52.08209],[4.3077,52.08356],[4.307274211471829,52.08387390249157]],[[4.30819,52.07789],[4.30844817,52.0775652],[4.30843,52.07755],[4.30884,52.07688],[4.30919084,52.07666072],[4.309250676431562,52.076610658496044],[4.30912,52.07672],[4.30819,52.07789]],[[4.30883,52.08102],[4.31039087,52.0795252],[4.3103,52.07888],[4.3104,52.07959],[4.31024,52.07997],[4.308948777972253,52.08115286773171],[4.30883,52.08102]],[[4.3093340240790035,52.07654091862778],[4.3096157998419695,52.075755330440586],[4.3101,52.0759],[4.3093340240790035,52.07654091862778]]
];


const poly = turf.polygon(coordinates, {
    stroke: '#FF0000',
    fill: '#FF0000',
    'fill-opacity': 0.2,
    'stroke-width': 1
});

const poly2 = turf.polygon(coordinates2, {
    stroke: '#222',
    fill: '#222',
    'fill-opacity': 0.5,
    'stroke-width': 1
});


const coords = coordinates[0]

const area = turf.area(turf.polygon([[...coords, coords[0]]]))
console.log("area = ", area)


const getAreaFromCurrentCoordinates = (currentCoordinates) => {
  const polygons = currentCoordinates.map(polygon => {
    if (polygon[0] !== polygon[polygon.length - 1]) {
      return turf.polygon([[...polygon, polygon[0]]])
    } else {
      return turf.polygon([[...polygon]])
    }
  })
  
  const area = polygons.reduce((acc, polygon) => {
    console.log("turf.area =",turf.area(polygon))
    return acc + turf.area(polygon)
  }, 0)
  console.log("area_vvv=", area)
  return area
}



const final = getAreaFromCurrentCoordinates(coordinates2)
console.log("final=",final)



return turf.featureCollection([poly, poly2]);




It seems that both "poly" and "poly2" are topologically invalid polygons and it does not make sense to compute their areas.

@user30184 what makes them topologically invalid polygons?
edit- is it because the first one for example is Non-Self-Intersecting?

The first poly has a self-intersection, the second one has a hole that lies outside the shell.

@user30184 do you know a way I can fix those coordinates so that I can calculate the area of it? Is there a turf method that can break the coordinates into multiple polygons so that I can calculate the area?

Sorry, I do not know turf.

@user30184 if you could use any tool how would you approach this problem?

Typically a function that corrects topology errors has "makevalid" in its name.
